# How to set path with glob when the fileName is use for csv?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, glob

I'm looking for a solution about path making for glob and for pandas to_csv anyone have a solution ?

My code :

```
from glob import glob
import json
import pandas as pd

PathIn = 'c:\\Users\\***\\PycharmProjects\\Project\\In'
PathOut = 'c:\\Users\\***\\PycharmProjects\\Project\\Out'

for fileName in glob(PathIn + '*.json', recursive=True):
    with open(fileName, 'rb') as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)
    print(json_dict)
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    df.to_csv(PathOut + fileName + '.csv', sep=";")
```

He doesn't print me my JSON file so don't take any file in my In. And I don't have any CSV in my Output.

Comment: check your indentation, if you want to work with f then it needs to be indented inside your with statement as otherwise the file will be closed. your code in its current form is not syntatctically correct.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle oups sorry it's just when i create the post but all of the code is into the statement

Comment: have you tried simplyfying your problem? and just printing the files to see if your reading what you expect. for example `for fileName in glob(PathIn + '*.json', recursive=True):` is the same as writing `glob('c:\\Users\\***\\PycharmProjects\\Project\\In' + ''*.json''` which is the same as saying `glob('c:\\Users\\***\\PycharmProjects\\Project\\In*.json''`

Comment: I think your problem is in the way you're writing your directory, I'd suggest to use `os.path.join(PathIn, '*.json')` and then for writing it `os.path.join(PathOut, filename)`, otherwise you'll miss a `\`.

Comment: Try putting a `\\` on the end of the input and output dirs

Comment: @ChrisDoyle If I don't use In file and all of my file are in the same directory of the programme yes the print return me all the json files. So my problem come from my path configuration... but I don't know where.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle If I put \ at the end that's work but he don't create me an csv file `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'c:\\Users\\***\\PycharmProjects\\Partage\\Out\\c:\\Users\\***\\PycharmProjects\\Partage\\In\\Asterion.json.csv'`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle can you help me to you it properly ? because it's the first time I use it

Comment: You just need to remove the `.json` from your filename.

Comment: @toti08 if I remove the '*json' that's make me this error : `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\Users\\***\\PycharmProjects\\Partage\\In\\'`

Comment: @PunkyLama I meant when you write it to the out directory, not when you read it.

Comment: And if I use os I get this error : `with open(fileName, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the key here is you want to create the output file in the relevant user dir based on the input file, so you could instead just get a list of the users dirs and iterate over each of them settting the in and output file then search the json files and create the csv in the coresponding dir. something like.

```py
import json
from glob import glob
import os.path as op
basepath = r'C:\Users\***\PycharmProjects'
_in = 'In'
_out = 'Out'
suffix = '\*.json'
output_suffix = '.csv'

for path in glob(basepath):
    in_dir = op.join(path, _in)
    out_dir = op.join(path, _out)
    for json_file in glob(in_dir + suffix, recursive=True):
        in_file_name = op.basename(json_file)
        out_file_name = in_file_name.split('.')[0] + output_suffix
        output_file = op.join(out_dir, out_file_name)
        with open(json_file) as jf:
            json_data = json.load(jf)
        print(json_data)

        ###do some stuff with the json

        with open(output_file, 'w') as of:
            of.write("some data or json stuff")
```

Comment: Yes but how can I take the file name when use pandas because I use dataframe for configure my CSV

Comment: what do you mean? in yout post you open the file from a path. why nowyou say how can i take the file name?

Comment: `df.to_csv(PathOut + fileName + '.csv', sep=";")` I use the filename to create my CSV and in you example you create the csv without pandas dataframe it's write in the code I use pandas

Comment: so just do `df.to_csv(output_file, sep=";")` since we have already created the output file path / name

Comment: Okk I see I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

Just slightly modifying your code I think you missed a `\` when writing the path for searching in the input directory.
For the output directory you need to build your filename by replacing the extension `.json` with `.csv`. There are many ways to do that:

```
for fileName in glob(PathIn + '\*.json', recursive=True):        
    with open(fileName, 'rb') as f:
        json_dict = json.load(f)
        print(json_dict)

    out_file_name = os.path.split(fileName)[0] + '.csv'
    out_file_dir = os.path.join(PathOut, out_file_name)
    # Here do something with your output file
```

Comment: but outdir is just a string it wont be globed into user dirs, how will the outfile know which user dir the in file was from and know how to write it into the matching users out file dir?

Comment: From the OP code I see there's no connection between the file and the output directory, the code just checks for `.json` files in an input directory, does something with it and saves a corresponding `csv` file in an output directory. The only link between the input and output file is that they have the same name but different extension.

Comment: `PathOut = 'c:\\Users\\***\\PycharmProjects\\Project\\Out'` what do you think the `*` in the path out is meant to represent then?